# How can I separate a string in BigQuery into multiple columns without breaking up distinct words?

Tags: sql, string, split, google-bigquery

I'm trying to separate a string into two columns, but only if the total string's length is larger than 25 characters. If it's shorter than 25 characters, then I want it on the 2nd column only. If it's longer than 25, then I want the first part of the string to be in the 1st column and the second part of the string to be in the 2nd column.
Here's the kicker... I don't want words to be broken up. So if the total length of the string is 26, I know that I'll need two columns, but I need to figure out where to splice up the string so that only complete words are represented in each column.

For example, the string is "Transportation Project Manager". Since it has over 25 characters, I want the first column to say "Transportation Project" and the second column to say "Manager". "Transportation Project" has less than 25 characters but I want it to stop there since there isn't another complete word that would fit within the 25 character limit.

Another example- The string is "Caseworker I". Since it's less than 25 characters, I want the whole string to be represented in column 2.

Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 0):

Wow, this is a great interview question!  Here's what I came up with:

```sql
WITH sample_data AS 
(
    SELECT 'Transportation Project Manager' AS phrase
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Caseworker I' AS phrase
    UNION ALL
    SELECT "This's 25 characters long" AS phrase
    UNION ALL
    SELECT "This's 25 characters long (not!)" AS phrase
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Antidisestablishmentarianist' AS phrase
),
unnested_words AS --Make a dataset with one row per "word" per phrase
(
    SELECT 
        *,
        --To preserve the spaces for character counts, prepend one to every word but the first
        CASE WHEN i = 0 THEN '' ELSE ' ' END || word AS word_with_space
    FROM
        sample_data
    CROSS JOIN 
        UNNEST(SPLIT(phrase, ' ')) AS word WITH OFFSET AS i
),
with_word_length AS 
(
    SELECT 
        *,
        --This doesn't need its own CTE, but done here for clarity
        LENGTH(word_with_space) AS word_length
    FROM
        unnested_words
),
running_sum AS --Mark when the total character length exceeds 25
(
    SELECT 
        *,
        SUM(word_length) OVER (PARTITION BY phrase ORDER BY i) <= 25 AS is_first_25
    FROM
        with_word_length
),
by_subphrase AS --Make a subphrase of words in the first 25, and one for any others
(
    SELECT 
        phrase,
        ARRAY_TO_STRING(ARRAY_AGG(word), '') AS subphrase
    FROM
        running_sum
    GROUP BY 
        phrase, is_first_25
),
by_phrase AS --Put subphrases into an array (back to one row per phrase)
(
    SELECT 
        phrase, ARRAY_AGG(subphrase) AS subphrases 
    FROM 
        by_subphrase 
    GROUP BY 
        1
)
SELECT 
    phrase,
    --Break the array of subphrases into columns per your rules
    CASE WHEN ARRAY_LENGTH(subphrases) = 1 THEN subphrases[OFFSET(0)] ELSE subphrases[OFFSET(1)] END, 
    CASE WHEN ARRAY_LENGTH(subphrases) = 1 THEN NULL ELSE subphrases[OFFSET(0)] END
FROM 
    by_phrase
```

Not very pretty but gets it done.

Comment: Thanks Jared. This looks fantastic, are you kidding me?!

Answer (score 0):

In order to split a string into 2 columns respecting a defined maximum length (following the logic you described), we will use [JavaScript User Defined Function in BigQuery (UDF)](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/user-defined-functions#javascript-udf-structure) together with the builtin function [LENGTH](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/functions-and-operators#length).

First, the string will be analysed. If the character after the maximum threshold is a white space then it will be split at the given maximum string length. However, if this is not the case, every single character will be checked, counting backwards, until a white space is found and the string will be split. Having this procedure, avoids the function to break up a word and it will be always split respecting the maximum allowed length.

Below is the query with some sample data,

```
CREATE TEMP FUNCTION split_str_1(s string,len int64)
RETURNS string
LANGUAGE js AS """
var len_aux = len, prev = 0;

//first part of the string within the threshold 
output = [];

//the rest of the string wihtout the first part
output2 = [];

//if the next character in the string is a whitespace, them split the string  
if(s[len_aux++] == ' ') {

    output.push(s.substring(prev,len_aux));
    output2.push(s.substring(prev,s.length));

}
else{
      do {
          if(s.substring(len_aux - 1, len_aux) == ' ')
            {
                 output.push(s.substring(prev,len_aux));
                 prev = len_aux;
                 output2.push(s.substring(prev,s.length));  
                 break;
           }len_aux--;
       } while(len_aux > prev)     
      }
      
//outputting the first part of the string      
return output[0];
""";

CREATE TEMP FUNCTION split_str_2(s string,len int64)
RETURNS string
LANGUAGE js AS """
var len_aux = len, prev = 0;

//first part of the string within the threshold 
output = [];

//the rest of the string wihtout the first part
output2 = [];

//if the next character in the string is a whitespace, them split the string  
if(s[len_aux++] == ' ') {

    output.push(s.substring(prev,len_aux));
    output2.push(s.substring(prev,s.length));

}
else{
      do {
          if(s.substring(len_aux - 1, len_aux) == ' ')
            {
                 output.push(s.substring(prev,len_aux));
                 prev = len_aux;
                 output2.push(s.substring(prev,s.length));  
                 break;
           }len_aux--;
       } while(len_aux > prev)     
      }
      
//outputting the first part of the string      
return output2[0];
""";

WITH data AS (
SELECT "Trying to split a string with more than 25 characters length" AS str UNION ALL
SELECT "Trying to split"  AS str
)
SELECT  str,
        IF(LENGTH(str)>25, split_str_1(str,25), null) as column_1,
        CASE WHEN LENGTH(str)>25 THEN split_str_2(str,25) ELSE str END AS column_2
FROM data
```

And the output,

[image]

Notice that there are 2 JavaScript UDF's, this is because the first one returns the first part of the string and the second returns the second part, when the string is longer than 25 characters. Also, the maximum allowed length is passed as an argument, but it can be statically defined within the UDF as `len=25`.

Comment: Thanks so much for your help. This looks like it'll work!

Answer (score 0):

I think your angle of attack should be to find the first space before the 25th character and then split based on that.

Using other submitted answers phrases as sample data:

```
 with sample_data as(
  select 'Transportation Project Manager' as phrase union all
  select 'Caseworker I'as phrase union all
  select "This's 25 characters long" as phrase union all
  select "This's 25 characters long (not!)" as phrase union all
  select 'Antidisestablishmentarianist' as phrase union all
  select 'Trying to split a string with more than 25 characters in length' as phrase union all
  select 'Trying to split' as phrase
),
temp as (
  select 
    phrase,
    length(phrase) as phrase_len,
    -- Find the first space before the 25th character
    -- by reversing the first 25 characters
    25-strpos(reverse(substr(phrase,1,25)),' ') as first_space_before_25 
  from sample_data
)
select 
  phrase,
  phrase_len,
  first_space_before_25,
  case when phrase_len <= 25 or first_space_before_25 = 25 then null
       when phrase_len > 25 then substr(phrase,1,first_space_before_25)
       else null
  end as col1,
  case when phrase_len <= 25 or first_space_before_25 = 25 then phrase
       when phrase_len > 25 then substr(phrase,first_space_before_25+1, phrase_len)
       else null
  end as col2
from temp
```

[image: Results]

I think this gets you pretty close using basic sql string manipulation.  You might need/want to clean this up a bit depending on if you want `col2` to start with a space or be trimmed, and depending on your cutoff point (you mentioned less than 25 and greater than 25, but not exactly 25).

Comment: THIS IS AMAZING! THANK YOU!

Answer (score 0):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

```
#standardSQL
SELECT phrase, 
  IF(IFNULL(cut, len ) >= len, NULL, SUBSTR(phrase, 1, cut)) col1, 
  IF(IFNULL(cut, len ) >= len, phrase, SUBSTR(phrase, cut + 1)) col2
FROM (
  SELECT phrase, LENGTH(phrase) len,
    (
      SELECT cut FROM (
        SELECT -1 + SUM(LENGTH(word) + 1) OVER(ORDER BY OFFSET) AS cut
        FROM UNNEST(SPLIT(phrase, ' ')) word WITH OFFSET
      )
      WHERE cut <= 25
      ORDER BY cut DESC
      LIMIT 1
    ) cut
  FROM `project.dataset.table`  
)
```

You can test, play with above using sample data (nicely provided in other answers) as in below example

```
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.table` AS (
  SELECT 'Transportation Project Manager' AS phrase UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Caseworker I' UNION ALL
  SELECT "This's 25 characters long" UNION ALL
  SELECT "This's 25 characters long (not!)" UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Antidisestablishmentarianist' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Trying to split a string with more than 25 characters in length' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Trying to split'
)
SELECT phrase, 
  IF(IFNULL(cut, len ) >= len, NULL, SUBSTR(phrase, 1, cut)) col1, 
  IF(IFNULL(cut, len ) >= len, phrase, SUBSTR(phrase, cut + 1)) col2
FROM (
  SELECT phrase, LENGTH(phrase) len,
    (
      SELECT cut FROM (
        SELECT -1 + SUM(LENGTH(word) + 1) OVER(ORDER BY OFFSET) AS cut
        FROM UNNEST(SPLIT(phrase, ' ')) word WITH OFFSET
      )
      WHERE cut <= 25
      ORDER BY cut DESC
      LIMIT 1
    ) cut
  FROM `project.dataset.table`  
)
```

with output

```
Row phrase                                                          col1                        col2     
1   Transportation Project Manager                                  Transportation Project      Manager  
2   Caseworker I                                                    null                        Caseworker I     
3   This's 25 characters long                                       null                        This's 25 characters long    
4   This's 25 characters long (not!)                                This's 25 characters long   (not!)   
5   Antidisestablishmentarianist                                    null                        Antidisestablishmentarianist     
6   Trying to split a string with more than 25 characters in length Trying to split a string    with more than 25 characters in length   
7   Trying to split                                                 null                        Trying to split
```

Note: if you want to get rid of leading (in col2) and trailing (in col1) spaces - you can just add TRIM() to handle this little extra logic

Comment: Thank you so much for the attention to detail. This looks like it will work! You're awesome!